# how to do real time notification in my (own)app?

Tags: android-notifications

i am new to android. i need develop notification to my application. i have seen  gcm (android hive) example and simple example of notification.

i was confused with that example.  please guide me how to do real time notication?

```
    mn = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_mail_add);
    nb.setTicker("hi");
    nb.setContentTitle("mail");

    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_mail);

Bitmap b= bd.getBitmap();
    nb.setLargeIcon(b);
    nb.setContentText("haii..");
    nb.setContentInfo("3 unread");
    nb.setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent in = new Intent(this,NotificationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    nb.setContentIntent(pi);
```